# mkfs.ext4 parameters

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ext4, format

I have a question about the ext4 filesystem and in specific about the tool `mkfs.ext4`.

```
mkfs.ext4  -j -O extent <device>
```

What does `-j` really do? In the manual it says that it creates an ext3 - journal. Why would I want that on an ext4 partition? Do I need this parameter at all to create a journal?

What about `-O` extent ? From looking at the manual it seems like this is a good idea, but are there any drawbacks?

So I guess what I am really asking is: What are recommended properties for a data partition (in detail: a logical raid 1 partition, which under the hood uses 2 HDD-partitions)?

Answer (score 2):

ext4 includes the journal and extents already, so specifying those options is redundant.   You want the journal because it protects ext3 and ext4 from corruption on an unclean shutdown.